# Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, iterator

```
for i in range(len(parsed_data)):
c = [('.'.join(re.findall("\d+",str(parsed_data[i][j].split()[:5]))) for j in range(len(parsed_data[i])))]
df_list.append(c)
index.append(dates[k] + c[0])
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-6babd754da6f> in <module>
      2     c = [('.'.join(re.findall("\d+",str(parsed_data[i][j].split()[:5]))) for j in range(len(parsed_data[i])))]
      3     df_list.append(c)
----> 4     index.append(dates[k] + c[0])

TypeError: Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Is `dates[k]` a generator?  Maybe you want to do `''.join(dates[k])`, or `''.join(map(str, dates[k]))`, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of parentheses around your list comprehension which makes it a one element list containing a generator instead of a list with the actual data.

replace:

```
[( '.'join... )]
```

with:

```
[ '.'join... ] # i.e. without the extra parentheses
```